# How to remove dependent vectors when determining an image

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

FIRST YR LINEAR ALGEBRA~

Having read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199125/how-to-remove-linearly-dependent-rows-cols) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2000278/how-to-find-the-image-of-a-matrix) answer, I'm still a little confused. I can understand, working backwards, how the answer is true, but I'd like to get a better understanding of WHY, so that I can work it out myself.
I have the matrix $A$:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
-1&1&1&3\\
2&-2&1&-3\\
3&-3&-2&-8\\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
which I reduced to RREF:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1&0&-2\\
0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
After reading I found out the image of $A$ is the span of its independent columns, and that the leading-$1$ columns are dependent columns. Using my introductory knowledge, I can't figure out why the the span of columns of $A$ would form the image. All I know of the image is that it's the set of all possible $y$ in $A\bar{x}=y$, and I can't visualize this.

If anyone can explain it as simply/visually as possible that'd be great (trying to find a video on Khan Academy, will let you know if I find one).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Atack Exchange.  The image of $A$ is the span of its column vectors because the columns are the images of the standard basis vectors and all vectors in the domain are linear combinations of the standard basis vectors so the image is the span of the column vectors for a transformation that’s linear

Comment: Thanks. Random side question, do you know of any user friendly (non-coding) plotters that I can use to plot vectors and their spans so that I can visualize things while studying?

Comment: Maybe there is something like that, but I’m not familiar with it - sorry

Comment: Another question so I don't have to open a new thread: what's the purpose of Math SE Meta? I can't seem to identify any specific use for it...

Comment: I think meta is for questions about how the site works, not math questions per se

Comment: Try expressing the product $A\vec x$ in terms of the columns of $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I found out the image of $A$ is the span of its independent columns... Using my introductory knowledge, I can't figure out why the the span of columns of $A$ would form the image. All I know of the image is that it's the set of all possible $y$ in $A\bar{x}=y$.

The possible $\bar x$ are $\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{bmatrix}.$

So the possible $y$ are 
$$
A\bar x =\begin{bmatrix}
-1&1&1&3\\
2&-2&1&-3\\
3&-3&-2&-8\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-x_1+x_2+x_3+3x_4\\2x_1-2x_2+x_3-3x_4\\3x_1-3x_2-2x_3-8x_4\end{bmatrix}$$

$$=x_1\begin{bmatrix}-1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}+x_2\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\\-3\end{bmatrix}+x_3\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\-2\end{bmatrix}+x_4\begin{bmatrix}3\\-3\\8\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Now can you see that the column vectors span the image?

Comment: Sorry I actually understood back when you made the original comments; wasn't sure what to do given you commented instead of answered like this. Is there a way to mark a comment as an answer?

Comment: You could upvote a comment, but I don't know of a way to mark a comment as an answer; you could have commented that my comment answered your question and should be posted as an answer